# How can I run cppcheck for specific files following a pattern?

Tags: c++, c, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I wanted to run the cppcheck only for specific type of files and not all files.

For example, I want to run cppcheck for all files ending with "Operation.cpp" recursively (basically for *Operation.cpp). I don't find an option in cppcheck, doing the same. Could anyone help?

Also, can I grep if a function is present in the CPP file, and throw error, if it is not present in those files.

Comment: What about some shell script, like `for i in (*Operation.cpp); do cppcheck $i; done`?

Comment: I'd use Clang-tidy instead.

Comment: @MathieuBunel Yes, this is something I was thinking. But is there a way to specify  in one call of cpp check?

Answer (score 3):

On Linux you can use

```
find foo*.cpp | xargs cppcheck
```

This is an update, previous example used `ls`, but as noticed by more experienced people, for automation purposes `find` should be preferable solution. Proof: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Why `ls`? `echo` would be just enough. Don't parse the output of `ls`. If so, why not just `cppcheck foo*.cpp` ?

Comment: This `ls` is an example. You can use additional options for ls, like recursive search in subfolders, that is what leverages it. Btw, how does `echo` help?

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Use `find` for recursive searches. `ls`is pretty printing.